# JSOUP find all images in HTML file with ALT attribute?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Hi I am relatively new to Java but I am hoping to write a class that will find all the ALT (image) attributes in a HTML file using JSOUP. I am hoping to get an error message printed if there is no alt text on an image and if there is to remind users to check it.

```
import java.io.File;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class grabImages {
                File input = new File("...HTML");
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "file:///C:...HTML");

                Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img"); 
                Elements alttext = doc.getElementsByAttribute("alt");

                 for (Element el : img){
                     if(el.attr("img").contains("alt")){
                         System.out.println("is the alt text relevant to the image? ");
                         }

                         else { System.out.println("no alt text found on image");
                         }
                    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think your logic was a little off.

For example:
Here you are trying to load the 'img' attribute of the 'img' tag...

```
el.attr("img")
```

Here's my implementation of the program. You should be able to alter it for your own needs.

```
 public class Controller {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            // Connect to website. This can be replaced with your file loading implementation
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.co.uk").get();

            // Get all img tags
            Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img");

            int counter = 0;

            // Loop through img tags
            for (Element el : img) {
                // If alt is empty or null, add one to counter
                if(el.attr("alt") == null || el.attr("alt").equals("")) {
                    counter++;
                }
                System.out.println("image tag: " + el.attr("src") + " Alt: " + el.attr("alt"));
            }
            System.out.println("Number of unset alt: " + counter);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks this answers my question, I was not quite sure how to implement the alt as it is an attribute of img but this clarifies it.

Comment: No problem! Let me know if there are any other confusions.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class grabImages {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
         Document doc;
     try {
         doc = Jsoup.connect("...HTML").get();
         Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img"); 

          for (Element el : img){
                                if(el.hasAttr("alt")){
                                    System.out.println("is the alt text relevant to the image? ");
                                }
                                else { 
                                    System.out.println("no alt text found on image");
                                }
                               }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
               }
}
```

**el.hasAttr("alt")** will give 'alt' attr is there or not.

for more informatiom 
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this by using [CSS selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to select the `img` that do not have `alt`, rather than iterating over every `img` in the doc.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    for (Element img : doc.select("img:not([alt])"))
        System.out.println("img does not have alt: " + img);
```