# How to read image "alt" attributes within links using jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to read `alt` attributes with the jsoup library?
For Example :

```
<a href="www.test.com"> 
    <img src="http://test.org/images/icon/socialNetwork/telegram-icon.png" border="0" alt="telegram"/>
</a>
```

How can read it?

Comment: I noticed that your HTML is incorrect `<imgsrc` instead of `<img src`, also the wrong quotes are used `”` instead of `"`. I fixed it, make sure to update your source.

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634215/jsoup-find-all-images-in-html-file-with-alt-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet, which reads all the `alt` attributes of the image tags:

```
String html = "<a href=\"www.test.com\"> <img src=\"http://test.org/images/icon/socialNetwork/telegram-icon.png\" border=\"0\" alt=\"telegram\"></img>";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = document.getElementsByTag("img");
for (Element e : elements) {
    String alt = e.attr("alt");
    System.out.println("alt:  " + alt);
}
```